# Fechar Load quando abrir modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu faço para parar o um gif, quando minha modal abrir?
 Quando eu clico no icon `FA-SEARCH` carrega minha modal, e o gif fica infinito.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.loading').hide();

        $('.fa-search').click(
                function () {

                    $('.loading').show();
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

```css
.loading {
    background: url('https://i.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.webp') no-repeat center center;
    background-color: #114876bf;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
}
<div class="loading"></div>
<a style="margin-left:-22px;" href="#" id="addCliente">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </a>
```

```
$("#addCliente").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        //alert(id);
        var url = '@Url.Action("adicionarCliente", "Atendimento", new { area = "Suporte" })';
        $("#addClientem").load(url,
            function() {
                $("#addClientem").modal();
            });
    });
```

Comment: seu modal é bootstrap?

Comment: é sim, eu editei, esqueci de colocar um script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode utilizar o método [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) para dar **hide** no loading e **show** no modal:

```js
$(() => {
  $('.loading').hide();

  $('.fa-search').on('click', () => {
      $('.loading').show();
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('.loading').hide();
        $('.modal').modal();
      }, 1000)
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.loading {
  background: url('https://i.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.webp') no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #114876bf;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="loading"></div>
<i class="fa fa-search">Ícone</i>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalExemplo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Título do modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar mudanças</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: esse é super simples, e de fácil implementação!! obg

Comment: Legal que ajudou man.

Comment: Desculpa, mas usar setTimeout pra isso é a pior solução, beirando a gambiarra. A modal do Bootstrap tem um callback pra isso, como informa a outra resposta.

Comment: Ahan, eu dei um exemplo e tem o outro exemplo, aí cabe a ele escolher o que ele vai implementar. Eu não acho gambiarra se o método te proporciona fazer aquilo!

Answer (score 2):

O bootstrap lança um evento onde você configura um callback para ser executado após o modal ser exibido. Exemplo:

```
$('#addClientem').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  //seu código aqui para pós abertura
})
```

Se tiver a necessidade de monitorar também o fechamento do modal mudar `shown.bs.modal` para `hidden.bs.modal`. Exemplo:

```
$('#addClientem').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  //seu código aqui para pós-fechamento
})
```

Comment: A melhor e mais consistente resposta. Parabéns! 